# Carrierwave PNG to JPG converter. How to avoid black background?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, carrierwave, rmagick

In paperclip, for example, it is possible to add this to set white background when .png is converted to .jpg:

```
:convert_options => { :all => '-background white -flatten +matte'}
```

Once carrierwave uses rmagick too, how to do that?

Obs.: My files are being stored in S3.

My code:

```
version :square do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
    process :convert => 'jpg'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach:

```
def resize_to_fill(width, height, gravity = 'Center', color = "white")
    manipulate! do |img|
      cols, rows = img[:dimensions]
      img.combine_options do |cmd|
        if width != cols || height != rows
          scale = [width/cols.to_f, height/rows.to_f].max
          cols = (scale * (cols + 0.5)).round
          rows = (scale * (rows + 0.5)).round
          cmd.resize "#{cols}x#{rows}"
        end
        cmd.gravity gravity
        cmd.background "rgba(255,255,255,0.0)"
        cmd.extent "#{width}x#{height}" if cols != width || rows != height
      end
      ilist = Magick::ImageList.new
      rows < cols ? dim = rows : dim = cols
      ilist.new_image(dim, dim) { self.background_color = "#{color}" }
      ilist.from_blob(img.to_blob)
      img = ilist.flatten_images
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's saner version that only does the conversion and background filling

```
def convert_and_fill(format, fill_color)
  manipulate!(format: format) do |img|
    new_img = ::Magick::Image.new(img.columns, img.rows)
    new_img = new_img.color_floodfill(1, 1, ::Magick::Pixel.from_color(fill_color))
    new_img.composite!(img, ::Magick::CenterGravity, ::Magick::OverCompositeOp)
    new_img = yield(new_img) if block_given?
    new_img
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
process convert_and_fill: [:jpg, "#FFFFFF"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using MiniMagick, I can just do this:

`process :resize_and_pad => [140, 80, "#FFFFFF", "Center"]`

Answer (score 1):

My solution with MiniMagick: first, define a method on your uploader to convert the image to jpg format that also removes the alpha channel and set the background color to white:

```
def convert_to_jpg(bg_color = '#FFFFFF')
  manipulate! do |image|
    image.background(bg_color)
    image.alpha('remove')
    image.format('jpg')
  end
end
```

Then add a new version that converts the file to jpg (also override the method `full_filename` to change the extension on the filename):

```
version :jpg do
  process :convert_to_jpg

  def full_filename(file)
    filename = super(file)
    basename = File.basename(filename, File.extname(filename))
    return "#{basename}.jpg"
  end
end
```